# Paging with large dataset- Linq2Sql, Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql, repeater, custompaging

I know such questions are in tonns on SO, but my question is little bit different. Generally , i found in SO, Custom Paging using Linq2Sql/ Sql. No I am not asking the same, i am done with that, my issue is with the pages(data pager) displayed on my asp.net page. 
In my table i have around 640 rows which will grow in future to thousands and even 10 thousands and more.

**what i did:**

1. For implementing the custom paging, i followed Mikes [this article](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/71/Search-Engine-Friendly-Custom-Paging-with-the-GridView-and-LINQ-to-SQL) and successfully implemented the custom paging on my records. I have a repeater on page and i am bind the data using Take and Skip as directed by Mike.
2. After implementing the paging, i found that its creating 10 records per page so in that case I got 64 pages displayed in my pager, which seems awkward. Its something like this
   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 upto 64, killing my page css and ui. Also it is not good , as user point of view. So

**What I want is that:**

I need SO User section like Pager... see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users)

**Finally I got solutions**

Thanks all of you, I got what i needed exactly. I am posting it as an answer below, so that it will help to others  requiring the same.

Comment: What you don't understand or have problems with?

Comment: If you can read my question properly, last two line says,i need SO User section like pager. I need some http reference or code samples to do the same.

Comment: There are many articles on how to do it. http://www.dotnetspeaks.com/DisplayArticle.aspx?ID=55 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9870486/dynamic-pagination-in-c-sharp Or/and you can always look for a tutorial using a different language, like php, and adapt the algorithms from there. It's always the same... Get number of pages and determine what to do with it.

Comment: I understood what you WANT, I just wanted to know what have you tried so far. But it seems you have problems googling basic principles, so look at my posted answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, I got what i needed exactly. I am posting it as an answer below, so that it will help other , needed the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I answered my own question, as this will help others who are looking for the same,,,,**

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11418/Pager-Control-for-ASP-NET : This is a custom control that I got on CodeProject. Very useful for those who needs Custom paging in ASP.Net, lightweight and easy to implement.